# jQuery for each div class find child and insertAfter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, each, children

I am editing my blog theme and I need to move (cut and paste) multiple specific divs under itself within a specific blog post.

The current HTML would be

```
<div class="blog_post text_post">
    <div class="post_container">
        <div class="bottom_meta"></div>
        <div class="post_date"></div>
        <div class="moreinfo"></div>
        <!-- I need .bottom_meta here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

I managed to make it work like this:

```
$(".blog_post.text_post .bottom_meta").insertAfter(".blog_post.text_post .moreinfo");
```

And on first sight it looks okay,but when I wrote another text post (usually posts are images) it makes a mess on my blog.
The code now moves .bottom_meta from both posts under both .moreinfo .

I tried using each function but I failed multiple times...

```
$(".blog_post.text_post").each(function(){     
     $(this).children(".bottom_meta").insertAfter.$(this).children(".moreinfo");
});
```

I tried the same with 'find' function instead of 'children',still a fail.

Can anyone help me out with this or at least point me out to the right direction.

Comment: Can you post some of your HTML as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
$(".blog_post.text_post").each(function(){     
    $(this).find(".bottom_meta").insertAfter($(this).find(".moreinfo"));
});
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/jjzpgr2x/)

- Change `.insertAfter.$(this).children(...)` to: `.insertAfter($(this).children(...))`
- Also, since the `.moreinfo`/`.bottom_meta` elements aren't direct children, you need to use `.find()` rather than `.children()`.

You can also simplify it to the following:

```
$(".blog_post.text_post").each(function () {
    $(".bottom_meta", this).insertAfter($(".moreinfo", this));
});
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/cc51r6an/)

Comment: That was quick :D
The first solution does not work for some reason. But second one works like a charm. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Morsus Yea, I edited it based on the HTML you provided. Both should work now. I added an explanation. Basically, `.find()` will find *all* children elements whereas `.children()` would only find direct children. The second solution is essentially just a shorthand for the `.find()` method.